# How to implement backdrop like this one in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Good morning .
i have this design here in figma and i want to turn it into code in android studio :
[The design in figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXjut.png)

how i can do this  and what is the name of the library of this layout . i tried backdrop layout but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Design a layout file for bar which contains rating, rate button and metascore. Add corner radius to its background (Top Left and Bottom Left). You can use cardview library. Use this layout in your original fragment. And set elevation. Front layers elevation should be bigger than back layer. Lowest elevation is 0 dp, biggest is 24 dp.
You can learn elevation more from this [link](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design) :